# How to compare three values between two arrays? [Fast way]

Tags: php, arrays

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'matrixUuid' => string '1' (length=17)
      'coursesUuid' => string '2' (length=17)
      'employeesUuid' => string '3' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'matrixUuid' => string '4' (length=17)
      'coursesUuid' => string '5' (length=17)
      'employeesUuid' => string '6' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'matrixUuid' => string '7' (length=17)
      'coursesUuid' => string '8' (length=17)
      'employeesUuid' => string '9' (length=17)
```

That is the  full list for the first array (around 1000records)

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'matrixUuid' => string '9' (length=17)
      'coursesUuid' => string '7' (length=17)
      'employeesUuid' => string '2' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'matrixUuid' => string '1' (length=17)
      'coursesUuid' => string '2' (length=17)
      'employeesUuid' => string '3' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'matrixUuid' => string '2' (length=17)
      'coursesUuid' => string '6' (length=17)
      'employeesUuid' => string '7' (length=17)
```

That is another one (200records)

```
array (size=3)
    'matrixUuid' => string '1' (length=17)
    'coursesUuid' => string '2' (length=17)
    'employeesUuid' => string '3' (length=17)
```

That is what I expected to result...

**I'm already using the recursive function with php 7, but it still takes a lot of time to load. Any ideas for those arrays search?**

```
<?php

public static function findElement($count, $obj, $element, $target)
{
    $obj = parseToArray($obj);
    $target = parseToArray($target);
    if ($count > 0) {
        foreach ($element as $key => $data) {
            if ($key == 0) {
                $find = ($obj[$count - 1][$data] == $target[$data]);
            } else {
                $find = $find && ($obj[$count - 1][$data] == $target[$data]);
            }
        }
        if ($find) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return self::findElement($count - 1, $obj, $element, $target);
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
array(0 => array('matrixUuid' => '1', 'coursesUuid' => '2', 'employeesUuid' => '3'), 1 => array('matrixUuid' => '4', 'coursesUuid' => '5', 'employeesUuid' => '6'), 2 => array('matrixUuid' => '7', 'coursesUuid' => '8', 'employeesUuid' => '9'));
```

Dummy data

Comment: Basically common elements among 2 arrays?

Comment: Generate Hashes and compare those.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes, using (matrixUuid, coursesUuid and employeesUuid ) I already finished grouping before a search

Comment: @BryantTang Please use `var_export` instead of `var_dump`, `print_r` when you want to receive fast answer of your question.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm Oh, it just an example for you easy the read, not the last result. I need to show on the web page as a number

Comment: @MarkusZeller It's should be a good idea!!

Comment: @BryantTang It's easy to read, but it's not easy to copy-paste and help you .. If you post array (or part of array in your case) with `var_export` it's much easier for us to help you ..

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm it's a part of the array in my case. I just change the number as 123456789 only for my case is using uuid_short() [sql]

Comment: You didn't get it .. I know it is part from array .. but I want to copy this array and try to help you, but in this form `'matrixUuid' => string '7' (length=17)` I cannot copy and use it .. that's why you should use `var_export()` when you paste arrays in SO.

Comment: really don't need a recursive function, just flatten em by assigning each as key for both, then make the comparison using array functions

Comment: here's dumb down version `$result = array_intersect(array_map('implode', $array1), array_map('implode', $array2));` but the concept is essentially the same with the use of implode

Comment: please show your best attempt (the recursive function you mention), there might already be optimization to be had in what you currently have. And what is _a lot of time_?

Comment: @jibsteroos
`public static function findElement($count, $obj, $element, $target)
 {
  $obj    = parseToArray($obj);
  $target = parseToArray($target);

  if ($count > 0) {
   foreach ($element as $key => $data) {
    if ($key == 0) {
     $find = ($obj[$count - 1][$data] == $target[$data]);
    } else {
     $find = $find && ($obj[$count - 1][$data] == $target[$data]);
    }
   }

   if ($find) {
    return 1;
   } else {
    return self::findElement($count - 1, $obj, $element, $target);
   }
  } else {
   return 0;
  }
 }`

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm `array(0 => array('matrixUuid' => '1', 'coursesUuid' => '2', 'employeesUuid' => '3'), 1 => array('matrixUuid' => '4', 'coursesUuid' => '5', 'employeesUuid' => '6'), 2 => array('matrixUuid' => '7', 'coursesUuid' => '8', 'employeesUuid' => '9'));`

Comment: @BryantTang kindly mark the solution as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly what you need but try this:

```
function compareArrays($arr1, $arr2)
{
   return strcmp(serialize($arr1), serialize($arr2));
}

$intersect = array_uintersect($arr1, $arr2, 'compareArrays');
$intersect = array_values($intersect);
print_r($intersect);
```

Comment: I tried to generate 10k+ values in both arrays, works instantly

Comment: That's is very faster to finish compare the data, Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

This is mostely just my thoughts and I'm not sure how fast it will work, but if we're talking about arrays with not very big length (not like millions or so) I'm thinking about the following algorythm:

1. Choose the shortest array
2. Parse it into the following struct:

```
[
    'matrixUuid1' => [
        'coursesUuid1' => [
            'employeesUuid1' => 1,
            'employeesUuid2' => 2,
            ...
        ],
        'coursesUuid2' => [
            ...
        ],
        ...
    ],
    'matrixUuid2' => [
        ...
    ],
    'matrixUuid3' => [
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

3. Just launch simple loop through the longest array:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($longest as $itm) {
    if (isset($prepared[$itm['matrixUuid']][$itm['coursesUuid']][$itm['employeesUuid']])) {
        $result[] = $itm;
    }
}
```